# FFImageLoading not shows webp image in Release Mode Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, ffimageloading

Set Build Action -> Bundle Resource. works fine in Local when deployed to device but not works in release mode.

Comment: Did you try to build your project with Armv7 only ? iOS Build -> Advanced -> Supported Architectures  -> ARMv7 .

Comment: Yes I have tried that too but not helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have resolved it by adding "--optimize=[+|-]remove-dynamic-registrar" in both Debug/Release mode. Hope it will help somebody.

[image]